# Update Location and Time After Vehicular Accident via Facebook

Tags: facebook, gps, gsm

I am a 4th year student studying Electrical Engineering. I'm doing a project for my final year about car security and a protection system. The first part of my project is to track stolen vehicle and send location update to owner's phone. I'm using GPS/GPRS/GSM Module Shield V3.0 and Arduino Uno for this. The first part is almost done.

Second part of my project is to alert the driver's near ones after an accident is occurred. I'm using pressure sensor and vibration sensor to detect the accident. I know it can be done by sending a text to the relatives from the GSM modem when an accident has occurred, but I was wondering if I can post an automatic Facebook status stating the time and location so the driver and car can be found easily. I cannot figure out how to get this part done or write the code. How do I get access to user's Facebook account? I am using C programming btw.

Can anyone explain me how can I accomplish it? Or, if you can name any other tutorial or forum discussion, that will be very helpful too. :)

Answer (score 3):

That would be prefilling and autoposting, both are not allowed on Facebook. We had a lot of discussions about this already in the Developers Group on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Point is, Facebook is not a notification system for everything, it´s a social network. Better use SMS, E-Mail or your own native App for those things.

I know it's for a good cause, but you will never get the required permission (`publish_actions`) approved for that. There is one way though, you would need to add all participants at least as Tester in your App. That way, you would not need to go through the review process. Although, it would still not be allowed according to the Facebook terms.

This would be the correct API endpoint btw: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I have to think of something else now